# The Hook registration_errors was not called

Tags: plugins, hooks

I can't validate the custom fields in my plugin. I want to skip some registration on WordPress. My code snippet is here:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'reg_user_register', 10, 3);
function reg_user_register($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";  /*need the values that are post from registration page*/
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();}
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please file an [edit] and explain. And please also keep in mind: Questions are references for later visitors. Format and write them as good as you can.

Comment: Are you using WP multisite?  registration_errors hook is called after user registration, but not on WP multiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the registration_errors hook properly.  It should look like this:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'reg_user_register', 10, 3);
function reg_user_register($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email){
    $custom_reg_field1 = $_POST["custom_reg_field1"];
    // add error checking here
    if ( empty($custom_reg_field1) ) {
        $errors->add('custom_reg_field1', __( 'Please enter a reg_field1.' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . There is no problem on parameter passing. Is any option to modify,validate the user-edit.php(admin side new user creation) . Any hooks for that ?

Comment: user-edit.php is not user registration.  User registration is wp-login.php?action=register... which is what registration_error hooks into.  If you wanted to hook into user-edit.php, I believe it is [user_profile_update_errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_profile_update_errors)

Comment: Thank you so much i resolve my problem i already use this hook on my plugin .. i just add some conditions . great answer thank you again